# HTTP Status 500 - org.apache.jasper.JasperException--Attribute name invalid for tag submit according to TLD

Tags: html, jsp, tomcat7, java-7, jsp-tags

I am using Tomcat 7 and JDK 1.7. 
I am not getting any error at the time of compiling the code but when I am hit the application URL, I am getting this error.

```
<html:submit value="Upload" name='dedupeUpload' style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 10pt; width: 110; height: 21" ></html:submit>
```

This perticular line is causing the exception.

Any help to resolve the issue will be greatfull for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't much detail about what tag library you are using here.  As in, what tag library is defined with the prefix="html" at the top of your JSP?  My answer is based on the assumption that this is a Struts tag.

If this is Struts, then you need to check what version of Struts jars you are using.  The "name" attribute on the "submit" tag does not exist before Struts 2.  I checked the tld on Struts 1.3.0 and the submit tag does not have a "name" attribute.  However, the Struts 2 tld does.

If you are using Struts, please check the version.